# Where is the .wine folder?

Tags: 11.10, wine, root, folder

In 11.04 the Wine folder was located in /home/"username"/.wine but now that I've done a fresh install of 11.10 and reinstalled Wine, the folder is nowhere to be found. There is a .wine text file in my home folder, but no .wine folder. I installed an exe and got no errors, but I just can't find the Wine folder with the Program Files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By itself, installing wine does not create the `.wine` folder.

Remove or rename the .wine text file - this could be confusing wine.

Run `winecfg` in a terminal - this will create the `.wine` folder in your home folder.